# How do I have the follow dashed span line effect?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I want to make the following:

[image]

This is my attempt:

```
<span class="cta-span"> or </span>

.cta-span {
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 18px;
color: #F3F3F3;
font-weight: 200;
background: url('line.png');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way would be to use `before` and `after` pseudo elements: **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/o2L9tknr/)**

```
.cta-span {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: red;
  font-weight: 200;
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  text-align:center;
  left:50%;
  top:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}
.cta-span:before,.cta-span:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  width:2px;
  height:70px;
  left:50%;
  transform:translateX(-50%);
  background-color:red;
}
.cta-span:before{
  top:-120px;
}
.cta-span:after{
  bottom:-120px;
}
```